# On which errors should curl retry for web API requests?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am implementing a class which retrieves information from a web API. It returns XML to HTTPS GET requests. I am using curl for the request and want it to retry in case of errors to make it more robust.

I am currently retrying (up to 3 times) for all curl errors and HTTP error 500, but I am wondering if that is the best approach.

So on which curl and http errors should I retry for my API requests? what is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd would say don't retry on `500` errors. That's some error on the API side and that's unlikely to change (at least, in a few seconds).

If you really want to retry on some responses, do it on timeouts, ie. [408](https://httpstatuses.com/408), [504](https://httpstatuses.com/504). It can be that the server is receiving more requests than it can handle, and waiting a few seconds to try again may be worthy.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree about 500 errors. The Mailgun API, for example, has returned intermittent 421 and 500 errors, and a retry might well succeed. Since you're only trying a few times and the errors should be rare, you might as well make more attempts when you get one.

I would retry on these HTTP errors:

408, 421, 429, 500, 502, 503, 504

There's a good explanation of what the codes mean [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)